# Как ассемблер получает адрес метки

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Как компилятор просчитывает адрес метки label, и как он будет использоваться после запуска программы? Также я заметил что при увеличении кода почему-то значение адреса меняется в инструкции `jle` после компиляции, почему?

Пример:

```
label:
    inc ax
    dec bx
    cmp ax, bx
    jle label
```

Пытаюсь понять как работают все компиляторы языка ассемблера, если скинете ссылку на гайд по этой теме буду очень признателен.

Comment: В данном случае используется относительное смещение (количество байт между меткой и концом команды перехода), происходит переход назад на определенное количество байт, а не по фиксированному адресу, поэтому фактический адрес компилятору знать не нужно. При ссылках по абсолютному адресу (например, на глобальную переменную) компилятор запоминает все адреса, где такие ссылки есть, добавляет их в специальную таблицу (таблица перемещаемых элементов), а при запуске готового экзешника система исправляет изначально рассчитанные адреса на фактические.

Comment: Количество байт между меткой и концом команды перехода. Вот тут я не очень понимаю. Я специально не менял положение метки и инструкцию перехода а только количество инструкций(которые находятся дальше перехода) и после компиляции этот самый offset менялся(создавал lst файл и в нем смотрел, возможно неправильно делал).

Comment: Я не знаю, что конкретно вы видите на листинге, поэтому никак прокомментировать не могу. Если смотреть бинарник в хекс-редакторе, то будет видно, что операндом условного перехода является однобайтное отрицательное (в дополнительном коде) относительное смещение.

Comment: Видимо я что-то попутал, это было то что мне нужно, спасибо. Как пометить ответ правильным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае в качестве операнда перехода фактически подставится не адрес метки, а относительное смещение - количество байт между адресом после команды перехода и адресом метки. Т.к. переход назад, то это будет отрицательное число в дополнительном коде.

Немного модифицирую ваш код для fasm:

```
use16

l1:
    inc ax
    dec bx
    cmp ax, bx
    jle l1
```

Компилирую (`fasm имя_файла.asm`), дальше смотрю полученный бинарник дизассемблером в 16-битном режиме:

```
00000000 40                             inc         ax                                  
00000001 4b                             dec         bx                                  
00000002 39d8                           cmp         ax, bx                              
00000004 7efa                           jng         0x0
```

Нас интересует последний байт - `fa`. Переводим из дополнительного кода в прямой (`0xFA - 0x100`) - получаем -6, что как раз численно равно количеству байт в программе (т.е. как я и говорил, количеству байт между меткой (адрес 0) и адресом после команды перехода `0x04+2 = 0x06`).